# What's the benefit of using $\text{d}F(x)$, rather than $f(x)\,\text{d}x$?

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

In many math-related textbooks and scientific journals, the writer and/or the authors frequently use $\text{d}F(x)$, instead of using $f(x)\,\text{d}x$. For example, for a random variable $X$ with a probability density function of $f$ defined over $\mathcal{X}$, instead of
$$\int_\mathcal{X} c(x) f(x) \, \text{d}x,\tag{1}\label{e1}$$
the following is used:
$$\int_\mathcal{X} c(x) \, \text{d} F(x),\tag{2}\label{e2}$$
where $c(x)$ is just an arbitrary function. (This is just an example...)

I believe that there must be some reasons of using \eqref{e2}, instead of using \eqref{e1}.
Can someone let me know them?

Comment: $F$ is a measure. The $dx$ represents the Lebesgue measure. Sometimes a measure can be represented (speaking **very** loosely) as a function times the Lebesgue measure but not always. For example, the cdf of a discrete distribution cannot be represented as an integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: For very concrete examples of what copper.hat is mentioning, you might look into Carter and van Brunt's _The Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integral: A Practical Introduction_, which goes into some depth about computing with measures $dF$, while remaining very practical and readable.

Comment: Even if $F$ is a nice continuous monotone increasing function, (which induces a measure in $\mathbb{R}$) there may not be a density function $f$ so that $F(x)=\int^x_{-\infty}f(t)\,dt$. For example, the [Cantor devil's staircase function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) does not admit a density with respect the Lebesgue measure, still $\int_A dF$ make sense as a measure.

Comment: $\int c(x) dF(x)$ may exist even when F is not differentiable so that $\int c(x) f(x)dx$ does not exist.

Comment: The function $f(x)$ doesn't always exist.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @HallaSurvivor, the $dF$ notation is often used for [Stieljes integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

An advantage is generality: such integrals can be used for continuous and discrete distributions (and any distribution with known CDF $F).$ In case of a purely discrete distribution, the integral becomes a finite sum or infinite series.

Familiar examples: If $F$ is the standard normal CDF, then $\int_R x\, dF(x) = 0;$ if $F$ is the CDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(n=10,p=1/2),$ then $\int_R x\,dF(x) = 5;$
and if $F$ is the CDF of a 50:50 mixture of these two distributions, then  $\int_R x\,dF(x) = 2.5$